# Работа с AudioInputStream

Tags: java, swing

Есть swing приложение 2d шутер, после добавления в игру аудио файла через AudioInputStream :

```
 public void playMusic(){
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("MainMusic.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

музыка играет как нужно, всё двигается как следует, но провисает реализация анимации противников. Я подумываю что это скорее всего из-за того что при добавлении музыки создается поток, есть ли возможность это исправить без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: без музыки всё нормально двигается?

Comment: Да, анимация отрабатывает как положенно, если что, то анимация это перерисовка героя, сменой картинок.

Comment: попробуйте в отдельный поток тогда добавить звук. Работали с потоками?

Comment: Вот с этим ещё не разбирался, я только знаю что они неявно могут меняться между собой

Comment: Вот почитайте [статью](http://java-online.ru/java-thread.xhtml), особенно в самом конце про пункт Trade. Думаю, будет полезно. Мне когда-то это помогло. Вам нужно для текущей анимации сделать отдельный поток и для звука. В принципе, у вас анимация может идти в рамках Main - это первый поток, а вот звук, сделать класс, который расширяет Thread и в нем сделать так. В итоге, у вас будет Main и еще 1 поток.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас почитаю

Comment: Да, не за что. Проблему вы уже знаете. Если будут проблемы с реализацией, тогда обновите вопрос и, уже люди помогут)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй создать отдельный поток для проигрыша музыки. Пример кода:

```
/*another code*/
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
    try {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("MainMusic.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }  
  }
}).start();
```